# Multiresolution modifier not working for bake

Tags: texture-baking, baking, multiresolution

I'm trying to bake some normal map details onto a low poly model using a multires modifier. I set up the image texture, made sure both the object and image textures are selected in the viewport and shader editor, and I'm using CPU to bake. However, when I actually click 'Bake', I get an error saying "Multires data baking requires multi-resolution object".

I don't know what to do. The object **has** a multires modifier, but I'm still getting an error saying the object needs a multires modifier.

Additionally, and I don't know if this has something to do with 2.8, I can no longer change subdivisions for sculpt mode and preview independently. The option is just not even listed in my multires modifier.

[image][image]

Comment: What if you apply the multi resolution modifier ?

Answer (score 0):

Create new or choose existing texture for bake to in material node editor and make it active by selecting it.

Then set preview subdivisions number of modifier to 0 before multires baking.

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.

edit: I'm now getting a "You should have active texture to use multires baker" error.

Comment: answer updated with first paragraph

Comment: I created a new texture and made it the active texture, but I was still receiving the error. I went into edit mode and assigned the new texture to the whole model and the bake worked.

Answer (score 0):

remove the subsurf modifier, if that does not work maybe make a duplicate and remove the armature aswell. So the only modifier is the multi res